# YouTube Premium doesn't play the video in the background but only shows thumbnail instead, and screen starts flickering

Tags: youtube

With YouTube Premium, the video will not play in the background, but only the thumbnail will appear. When you tap it open, the screen starts flickering.

[image]

Comment: is it the latest version of youtube?

Comment: Can you provide the device model, Android version, and whether you're using custom ROM or not?

Comment: @andrew                                                    
Android 10, Stock rom (realme ui 1).   Device model: Rmx2001